# How to use Ward identity to abbreviate the photon propagator into $\frac{-i\ g_{\mu\nu}}{q^2 (1- \Pi(q^2))}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, propagator, ward-identity

How to derive abbreviated form (equation 7.75) from original form (equation 7.74) via Ward identity? (In Peskin's QFT Charpter 7 P246)

I still can't see this result after read this paragraph many times.

[image]

Comment: The Ward identity is nothing else than current conservation $\partial_\mu j^\mu(x)=0$ translated into Fourier (momentum) space, i.e. $q_\mu \tilde{j^\mu}(q)$ (you should find this somewhere in your book). So, as the book says, the terms $\sim q_\mu q_\nu$ multiplied with a fermion current $\tilde{j}^\mu(q)$ vanish.